# Building function to read selected datasets from repository

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment

New to coding - I have a collection of data from a number of sensors.

For analysis purposes, I wanted to build a function that intakes a list of sensor numbers and creates/names variables as dataframes.

Currently what I've written:

```
    # establish directory
    setwd("C:/Users/thoma/Desktop/Files/Programming/R/timeseries_sensor_data/")

    # define function
    read_censor_data <- function(id = 1:99){
            for(i in id){

                    # create a variable name for every sensor || read csv
                    assign(paste0("sensor_",i),read.csv(paste0(i,'.csv')))
                    print(paste0("Sensor_",i," has been succesfully read."))
            }
    }
    read_censor_data(12:19)
```

The for loop is going through the selected input of 12 to 19, but no dataframe variables have been created.

Could anyone suggest where I'm going wrong and how I might fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the environment appropriately as the data is created only in the function.

```
read_censor_data <- function(id = 1:99){
   for(i in id){
    assign(paste0("sensor_",i),read.csv(paste0(i,'.csv')), envir = parent.frame())
    print(paste0("Sensor_",i," has been succesfully read."))
  }
}

read_censor_data(12:19)
```

However, it is usually not a good practice to create a lot of dataframes in the global environment from a function. Consider using lists instead which are easier to manage.

```
read_censor_data <- function(id = 1:99){
   lapply(paste0("sensor_", id), read.csv)
}

list_df <- read_censor_data(12:19)
```

You can then access each individual dataframe with `list_df[[1]]`, `list_df[[2]]` etc.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! 
The reason I want to create dataframes within this function is that its a broad all-purpose function I want to utilise in a larger script (ie: analyse data from highest 10 sensors, odd sensors only etc.).